# JSF - Browse and print values from ArrayList<String[]> using EL

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, facelets, el

I have an ArrayList from a Bean :

```
...
public ArrayList<String[]> getArticleList() {
    ...
}
...
```

I need to print these values (with getter method) by using EL on JSF2 (such as `#{bean.articlesLage}`

How can I do this? Cheers

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't remember if JSF supports arrays, however if you can convert your `ArrayList<Array>` to `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>`, then something like this should work

```
<ui:repeat value="#{bean.articleList}" var="t">
   <ui:repeat value="#{t}" var="s">
      #{s}
   </ui:repeat>
</ui:repeat>
```

Comment: Nice One. And if i want to select the index 2 for each string[]?

Comment: What do you mean select the index 2?

Comment: I mean : my `ArrayList<String[]>` has more `String[]`. If my first `String[]` in the arraylist is `[hello, im, marco]` and the second is `[how, are, you]` I would like to print values `marco` and `you` (which are at the 2° position for each `String[]`.

Comment: The `#{s}` refers to the individual `String` item of `String[]`. The `#{t}` refers to individual `String[]` item of the `List<String[]>`. So you want to get rid of nested `ui:repeat` and use `#{t[2]}` instead.

Comment: What about If I want to edit values of ArrayList by putting `h:inputText` inside `ui:repeat`?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19395621

Answer (score 2):

You can use a nested ui:repeat or a nested datatable like this with your current model ArrayList :

```
<h:dataTable value="#{bean.articleList}" var="row">
    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="COL" />
        </f:facet>
        <h:dataTable value="#{row}" var="nested_row">
            <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="COL" />
            </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{nested_row}" />
            </h:column>
    </h:dataTable>          
    </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

Comment: Why rich? richfaces is not tagged

Comment: Was an example using the RichFaces component, The std JSF datatable (prefix h:) can do the same thing.