# Using inputText inside ui:repeat to update ArrayList of values is not working

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

As referring to Post's title., I'm trying to update the values of ArrayList from `h:inputText` inside `ui:repeat`, which is not working.
Please see the following mock up for further understanding:

I have a POJO class as follows:

```
public class User implements Serializable{
    private String name;
    private List<String> emails;

    public User(String name, List<String> emails) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.emails = emails;
    }
    //Setters Getters
}
```

In my Manager I have created list of User POJOS:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class UserManager implements Serializable {
    private List<User> userList;
    public UserManager() {
        userList = new ArrayList<User>();
        ArrayList<String> emails= new ArrayList<String>();

        emails.add("user1.1@mail.com");
        emails.add("user1.2@mail.com");
        userList.add(new User("User1", (List<String>) emails.clone()));

        emails.clear();
        emails.add("user2.1@mail.com");
        emails.add("user2.2@mail.com");
        userList.add(new User("User2", (List<String>) emails.clone()));
    }
    public void action(){
    for(User u : userList){
        System.out.println(u);
    }
}
    //Setters Getters
}
```

Now in my Facelet I'm Using `ui:repeat` to load the data to `h:inputText` in to table, so that user can edit and change the values.
Facelet Code:

```
<h:form id="userForm">
    <table border="1">
        <ui:repeat var="user" value="#{userManager.userList}">
            <tr>
                <td><h:inputText value="#{user.name}"/> </td>

                <ui:repeat var="email" value="#{user.emails}">
                    <td><h:inputText value="#{email}"/> </td>
                </ui:repeat>
            </tr>
        </ui:repeat>
    </table>

    <h:commandButton value="Save" action="#{userManager.action}">
        <f:ajax execute="@form @this"/>
    </h:commandButton>
</h:form>
```

The above approach works fine when I edit the `#{user.name}` but its not working with `#{email}`.
I can assume the its working for `#{user.name}` because `name` has setter and getter methods.
So how do I update the `emails` list object.
Is my POJO design is poor? or Is it a bad idea to use `ui:repeat`?
How can I achieve this?

*Note: my current Mojarra version is 2.1*

Comment: Are you not able to see the email list or what ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As BalusC reported [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10784078/11544) `String` is immutable.

Use the `varStatus` attribute to access directly the list member by the index.

```html
<ui:repeat varStatus="loop" value="#{user.emails}">
    <td><h:inputText value="#{user.emails[loop.index]}"/> </td>
</ui:repeat>
```

With BigDecimals:

```html
<ui:repeat varStatus="loop" value="#{user.numbers}">
    <td><h:inputText value="#{user.numbers[loop.index]}" converter="javax.faces.BigDecimal"/> </td>
</ui:repeat>
```

Comment: Will it work for any the type inside ArrayList?

Comment: Well if your input's value is bound to something else than String, you'll need a converter.

Comment: Ok thanks for the answer, just one last doubt.  What If I have List of BigDecimal types?

Comment: Just updated my answer to show how to use the BigDecimal converter