# updating an empty integer array inside ui:repeat

Tags: arrays, jsf, uirepeat

I want to use ui:repeat to fill values of an integer array which is originally empty, from inputText. I followed the explanation in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19395621/using-inputtext-inside-uirepeat-to-update-arraylist-of-values-is-not-working), but it did't work for me. My UI is:

```
<ui:repeat value="#{controllerBean.schedule.scheduleTimes}" var="v" varStatus="loop">
    <h:outputText value="Shedulte Time #{loop.index + 1}">
    </h:outputText>
    <p:inputText value="#{controllerBean.schedule.scheduleTimes[loop.index]}">
    </p:inputText>
</ui:repeat>
```

contollerBean is the managed bean, schedule is model and scheduleTimes is Integer[] array in my model with setter and getter. After providing some values on ui, the values of the array at each index is still null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>You need a converter to `Integer` because in JSF all values are by default treated as `String`.</strike>

```
<ui:repeat value="#{controllerBean.schedule.scheduleTimes}" var="v" varStatus="loop">
    <h:outputText value="Shedulte Time #{loop.index + 1}">
    </h:outputText>
    <p:inputText value="#{controllerBean.schedule.scheduleTimes[loop.index]}" converter="javax.faces.Integer">
    </p:inputText>
</ui:repeat>
```

Now the example works for me like a charm.

---

My previous answer is incorrect because JSF automatically converts primitive types. A converter is however required for Collections because expected type cannot be determined at runtime.

Nevertheless the example works with a converter or without. Therefore please make sure that `controllerBean` has scope other than non-scoped (without scope annotation). Otherwise the bean is recreated each time you access it.

---

Well, also with request scope my code works fine. Please check the 
[example I'm using](https://github.com/destin/SO-answers/tree/master/SO-updating-an-empty-integer-array-inside-uirepeat)

I replaced primefaces p:inputText with pure JSF h:inputText but I don't think it matters. I also added some html table tags to do a formatting.

As you can see in server logs values are set properly.

Comment: Yes, your previous answer didn't work. I am using request scope for the bean.

Comment: I updated my answer with example project that I'm using. Maybe you can compare your project with mine and spot some difference.

Comment: I appreciate your effort Dawid. Your code works fine. But, I discovered that my problem is related to the size assignment of scheduleTimes array. I want to accept its size from selectOneMenu using valueChangeListener, create the array based on this value on value change, and then use it on the ui:repeat. The problem i think is b/c the array is created after the construction of managed bean.

Comment: I have changed bean to view scoped and now works. Sorry for not explaining the details...